# result with code is fine but last column 'update' show not active with href

Tags: php

result with code is fine but  last column 'update'  show not active with 
     href

```
 <?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 ?>

 <tr><th colspan="4">Image</th><th>Title</th><th>Details</th>  
<th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4"><img src="<?php echo $row['image']?>"width="50px" 
height="50px" > </td>
<td><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['details']?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['country']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['city']?></td>

<td><a href ="#">update</a></td>

</tr>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Hmm, Blockquote? Also what are you talking about?

Comment: so just replace your `href ="#"` with some real link if you need ex : `href ="http://example.com/recordUpdate.php"`

Comment: i mean i have table with 6 column , the last column (update) contian href  , when run program the last column printed but i cant click on it because its disable Despite that the link works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you are using the `href` value as `#` for your `update` link! Instead, you should use a URL there. Because when you click on the link, the browser takes you to the page that you had specified in that `href` attribute!

So in short, replace this:

```
<td><a href ="#">update</a></td>
```

with something like this:

```
<td><a href ="update_page.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
```

Hope it helps.